# Sampling a Midi file with a sound file?

Tags: midi, sampling

I have looked everywhere on the internet and could not find anything similar to what I am trying to do. I need to change the instrument of a midi file into custom .wav or .mp3 sound files, so the sound file plays for as long as the note and has the same pitch, each time there is a note. Is there a free program that lets me do this?

Answer (score 3):

The most widely used standard for specifying sounds for a MIDI synthesizer is [SoundFont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundFont), which contains all samples and control information in a single file.

You need some [SoundFont editing tool](https://musescore.org/en/node/13734), and some [software synthesizer that can use sound fonts](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundFont#Freie/kostenlose_Synthesizer).